# Unable to Generate Link error when using Dropbox Chooser SDK for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

In my app, I've already integrated Dropbox Sync SDK. So when the Dropbox Chooser SDK for iOS comes in, I give it a try.

My question is, when I tested on my actual device, it says

> "Unable to Generate Link. Sorry, an error occurred. Please try again later."

// Note: They say "You may have a project that requires multiple app keys because it also uses the Core or Sync API. In this case, you'll need to explicitly initialize your own instance of the Chooser with the right app key by using the -initWithAppKey: method."

**Update:**
Because I already has the same URL scheme for the Sync API, so what I did was to initialize another instance of Chooser with `-initWithAppkey:` method in both -`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` in my **AppDelegate**

```
-(BOOL)  application:(UIApplication *)application
             openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
          annotation:(id)annotation
{
  // instantiate a new DBChooser instance with Chooser Key
  // .. make sure it should not include 'db-' prefix
  DBChooser *chooser = [[DBChooser alloc] initWithAppKey:@"my-chooser-key"];
  if ([chooser handleOpenURL:url]) {
      // This was a Chooser response and handleOpenURL automatically ran the
      // completion block
      return YES;
  }

  return NO;
}
```

... and my top most  view controller.

```
- (void)didPressChoose
{
    // .. make sure it should not include 'db-' prefix
    DBChooser *chooser = [[DBChooser alloc] initWithAppKey:@"my-dropbox-key"];
    [chooser openChooserForLinkType:DBChooserLinkTypeDirect
                                fromViewController:self
                                        completion:^(NSArray *results)
    {
       if ([results count]) {

           // Process results from Chooser
           _result = results[0];
           NSLog(@"%@", _result.link);
       } else {

           // User canceled the action
       }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like some connection issue, or otherwise some issue Dropbox-side. Open a ticket using the "API support" link on https://www.dropbox.com/developers for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do the request with the right app-key. Not the one you use for the syncer, but a new Drop-in app with its own app key.

If you did that, try to manage your own instance of the `DBChooser`. Now you take an instance and call an `init`-method on it. You should manage your own singleton instance which you share through you app. You should create that instance with `[[DBChooser alloc] initWithAppKey:@"my-dropbox-key"]`. Never use the defaultChooser in your case.